# After migration from rails 5.1 to 5.2, an error 'TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into Hash' appears on model reindexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

After I upgraded rails from 5.1 to 5.2 and [Searchkick gem](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) was also upgraded to version 4.3, then I tried to run `reindex` on my models, but an error appears on every single one for test and development environments.

 
`TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into Hash` 

 
Stack trace from (dev env):

```
[1] pry(main)> Model.reindex
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into Hash
from /Users/vadymfilipov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge.rb:24:in `merge!'
```

Stack trace from (test env):

```
TypeError:
  no implicit conversion of nil into Hash
# /Users/vadymfilipov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge.rb:24:in `merge!'
# /Users/vadymfilipov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge.rb:24:in `deep_merge!'
# /Users/vadymfilipov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge.rb:19:in `deep_merge'
# /Users/vadymfilipov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/searchkick-4.3.0/lib/searchkick/index_options.rb:287:in `index_options'
# /Users/vadymfilipov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/searchkick-4.3.0/lib/searchkick/model.rb:65:in `searchkick_index_options'
# /Users/vadymfilipov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/searchkick-4.3.0/lib/searchkick/index.rb:286:in `reindex_scope'
# /Users/vadymfilipov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/searchkick-4.3.0/lib/searchkick/index.rb:201:in `reindex'
# /Users/vadymfilipov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/searchkick-4.3.0/lib/searchkick/model.rb:60:in `searchkick_reindex'
# ./lib/elastic.rb:9:in `map'
# ./lib/elastic.rb:9:in `reindex'
```

Comment: What was the previous version of SearchKick?

Comment: @Beartech it was: 2.4.0

Comment: Did you follow: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/master/docs/Searchkick-3-Upgrade.md

Comment: @Beartech, it helped, thanks.